# Version of Python when running Ansible commands

Tags: macos, ansible, python-3.6

I am using `OSX.10.12.6`.

I installed ansible via pip3 (in order to use it with Python3 considering Python2 is already installed on my machine by default) and downloaded the ec2.py external inventory script from Ansible github

But when running ansible commands, I get the error:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse 
~/ec2.py with script plugin: Inventory script
~/ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"~/ec2.py", line 130, in <module>     import boto ImportError: No module named boto
```

It seems to be because ansible is using Python2 instead of Python3 (I checked, I cannot import boto or ansible from Python2 but I can from Python3). Also I can run successfully the following `python3 ec2.py`

What is surprising is that if I run `ansible --version`, I get the following:

```
ansible 2.8.3
config file = ~/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/Users/XXXX/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
python version = 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]
```

Is there anything I can do to "force" ansible to use Python3 instead of Python2?

PS: Note that I can get through the initial error by pip install boto on Python2, but others error pop up and would rather use Python3

Comment: It looks like Ansible *is* using Python 3.  The output of `ansible --version` clearly shows `python version = 3.6.5`. It's possible it's using a *different* python 3 than what you're using when you run `python3` on the terminal. What is the output of `which python3`? What is the output of `head -1 $(which ansible)`?

Comment: Thanks. `which python3` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python3` whereas `head -1 $(which ansible)` gives me `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6`. So indeed it is different, but when entering into Python command for both, both are version 3.6.5 I can import boto for both without a problem. Note that I confirmed that by installing boto on Python2 via `pip2.7 install boto` I was able to successfully remove the prior error (but then it failed on the next import, `import ansible`. I think I am confused now =(

Comment: I think both `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6` and `/usr/local/bin/python3` are the same (pointing to the same install of Python), I am not sure how to test this formally, but I tested by `pip3 install` or `pip3 uninstall` some libraries and changes are reflected across both

Comment: @Vincent: `/usr/local/bin/python3` is very probably a link or wrapper.

Comment: thanks @VladimirBotka I thought so. Unfortunately this means my problem is still alive and well!

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD [Quarterly (Stable) Ports Branch](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Ports/QuarterlyBranch) released today [2019Q3](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/branches/) has [Ansible 2.7.10](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/branches/2019Q3/sysutils/ansible/distinfo?view=log). HEAD upgraded to [Ansible 2.8.3](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/sysutils/ansible/distinfo?view=log) last Sunday! The conclusion is, FreeBSD decided not to put 2.8.3 into the STABLE branch. Probably one of the reasons is the new feature in Ansible 2.8 [Python interpreter discovery](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.8/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.8.rst#major-changes). See [Using FLAVORS](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/flavors-using.html). Hence either you downgrade to Ansible 2.7, or you proceed with fixing the HEAD (in MacOS).

It might be worth to try and set [ansible_python_interpreter](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/50163) to Python 2.7.

---

<sup>(Some might argue it's rather a comment. I started there, but it's too long.)</sup>

Comment: thanks - i downgraded ansible but it did not solve the problem. I could not figure out how to set ansible_python_interpreter to Python3.6 (so i worked around this by installing boto and ansible on Python2, not ideal...)

Comment: That's standard. I run Ansible 2.8.3 with Python 2.7.15 in Ubuntu. You should be glad if it's working for you with Python2. See [Python 3 Support](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html#python-3-support).